# fragment overlapping and activity

Tags: android, fragment

I got navigation bar on my left side of my `MainActivity` page, and then the action inside the navigation bar is all in `fragment`. When i click on any action, `fragment` overlapping my `MainActivity` page.

[image: Screenshot]

You can see there are `text` and `button` on it. 
How do I overcome this problem?
**Code**

```
public void selectedItemDrawer(MenuItem menuItem){
    Fragment myFragment = null;
    Class fragment = null;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){

        case R.id.checkIn:
            //Not yet complete
            break;

        case R.id.checkOut:
            //Not yet complete
            break;

        case R.id.applyOff:
            break;

        case R.id.reportBug:
            break;

        case R.id.manageProfile:
            fragment = fragment_manageProfile.class;
            /*
             * Here is the complete 1
             */
            break;

        case R.id.logout:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    try{
        myFragment = (Fragment)fragment.newInstance();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.viewPage, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();



    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawer.closeDrawers();
}
```

**First_layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/viewPage"
android:background="@drawable/login_background">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**2nd_layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In my `onCreate` method, i use 2nd layout to view the layout
`setContentView(R.layout.2nd_layout);`

Comment: what do you need? a background for your navigation drawer?

Comment: i want to solve this problem. I want to show my `fragmentActivity` from my navigation bar in a better look.

Comment: please post your side fragment layout xml

Comment: done. Please check it.

Comment: i can't understand well, try to change this line app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent" selecting a different color

Comment: ntg changed. even i delete the line. its ntg changes

Comment: have you add background in your fragment layout ?? You can try this if you dont have `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"`

Comment: @KopiBryant wow.. after add that line. Thats exactly what i want. 
small matter lead me to have headache for such a long time looking for ans. THANKS. BTW u can post your ans i will accept your answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"` in your fragment layout

Comment: accepted.. Thanks. But however, `iewPage` and `frameLayout` are they any different ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a background color for your NavitagionView. Into your xml do something like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/red"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**NOTE**

FrameLayout keeps it's children overlapped. It's his behaviour. If you don't want that you must use a different layout. Look at [there](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

Comment: this changes the color of the left side navigation bar into red color ..

Comment: yeah, and what is your problem? I understood that you have a transparent navigation view. please specify what you need

Comment: i want to view the `fragment` in perfect way. i dont wan that the `fragment` and `activity` is overlapping, you can see from my screenshot. I want like `fragment` activity background should be in the custom background color which will be black

Comment: so try to specify background color into your fragment xml

Comment: yes i did. U can see from the 1st_layout `<frameLayout` with `android:background="@drawable/login_background"`. but i didnt show.. i think it is overlapping fragment and activity. mayB somethings is wrong with my code.

Comment: I can't understand what you need. If you need to add a fragment over the other, like a transition from a section to another, you need to add or to replace your fragment using the fragment manager. Otherwise i can't figure out what is your desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping may be occurring due to the include tag in your first_layout.xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

remove that line and see if the overlapping stops.

Comment: but if i remove this line, then my activity will be empty right ?

Comment: No it won't, but it will only show the Coordinator Layout within the Framelayout (of first_layout.xml). I recreated the use case, and the overlapping occurs when the framelayout used for the fragment transaction to replace the fragments isn't empty. Removing the coordinator layout should stop the overlapping from occurring.

Comment: no.. i cant delete either coordinator or include layout. if i delete include layout.. --> my recycler view is empty and if i delete coordinator --> my collapsing and nav cant show